# Read-only from outside and not from inside

Tags: javascript, object, properties, readonly

Take a look at this object

```
var bob = {
    name    : "Bob",
    age     : 18,
    talk    : function() {
        console.log("hi");
    },
    growOld : function() {
        this.age += 30;
    }
}
```

I can access `bob.age` and use `bob.growOld()`. But what if I want `bob.age` to be read-only from outside and readable from inside? For example `bob.age = 20` won't work and I can only change the `age` property with a method of `bob` object.

I did some googling and managed to set a read-only property.

```
var bob = {
    name    : "Bob",
    talk    : function() {
        console.log("hi");
    },
    growOld : function() {
        this.age += 30;
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(bob, "age", {
    enumerable      : false,
    configurable    : false,
    writable        : false,
    value           : 18
});
```

I can't change `age` with `bob.age = 20`, but I also can't change it with the method. `bob.growOld()` doesn't change the `age` property. I thought setting `configurable` to `true` would do the trick, but it doesn't.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript offers many ways to do things and there are probably other ways to accomplish this, but this is a way that I could think of using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and an object literal.

Basically you declare bob as a public variable, then use an [iife](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to create a private space inside of where you create a private variable ("privateAge") and then add other properties to bob which will themselves be public but also have access to the scope of the iife.

Next, inside the iife you use object.property to declare the property you want to be exposed as read only ('age'), and redefine the `get` to return privateAge and, this is key, don't define `set` or define it do something else when is called.

Oh, and I guess I should mention that the get is called when `bob.age` is used and set is called when `bob.age` is used with the assignment operator (ex. `bob.age = 100`)

```
// Public out here
var bob;
// This is the iife
(function() {
  // Private in here
  var privateAge = 17;
  bob = {
    name    : "Bob",
    talk    : function() {
        console.log("hi");
    },
    growOld : function() {
        privateAge += 30;
    }
  }

  Object.defineProperty(bob, "age", {
    get: function() { return privateAge; },
    set: function(newValue) { 
      // This is how read only from the out side is achieved
      // You could throw an error here or just omit set completely
      console.log("Not yours!");
    } 
  });

}());

console.log(bob.age)  // 17
console.log(bob.privateAge) // undefined
bob.age = 100 // Not yours!
console.log(bob.age) // still 17
bob.growOld(); 
console.log(bob.age) // 47
```

Comment: This works in a way, but I'd have to change the structure of my code. Originally, I'm using a constructor to create an object, and there are other constructors which are called inside the main object. I don't know how should I implement this method to my code. I don't really want to change the structure. [**Actual code**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLdg79by/)